# Using different colors for text plot annotations

Tags: octave

I have an image plot with few pixels that I would like to annotate with a value at every pixel. Since the colors vary all over the regular colormap, I can't really have a fixed color for all the annotations, but would like to vary the color.

```
x=1:3;
y=1:3;
m(y, x) = x .* y' * 6;
image(m);
xi = repmat(x, 3, 1);
yi = repmat(y', 1, 3);
text(xi, yi, "label");
```

I can of course set the color using

```
text(xi, yi, "label", "color", "white");
```

Instead of `"white"` I tried both a 3D matrix

```
clabels = zeros(3, 3, 3);
clabels(:, :, 2) = 0.75; % for medium green, RGB = [0 192 0];
```

and a cell matrix

```
clabels = {};
clabels(y, x) = [0 0.75 0];
```

In both cases using `text(xi, yi, "label", color, clabels)` yielded me an

> error: invalid value for color property "color"

Is there a way to create a matrix-like value for the color property? Or do I have to create a `text` for every color I would like to annotate with?

Comment: This does not answer the question as it requires multiple text commands, but it might be helpful anyway. First determine whether the label should be black or white depending on the brightness of the pixel. `bw = colormap * [0.299; 0.587; 0.114]) > 0.5` Create a boolean matrix for black labels `bl = (bw==1)`and white ones `wh = (bw==0)`. Use these for the annotations: `text(xi(bl), yi(bl), "label", "color", "black")` and for white accordingly.

Comment: I can't edit the comment any longer. It should be `bl = (bw(m) == 1)` and `wh = (bw(m) == 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `{'Property'}, {values}` format to specify the colors for all text objects at once. Unfortuantely you can't do this directly in the constructor but you can perform the action on the array of text objects returned by `text` using `set`.

```
t = text(xi, yi, 'label');

% Create a cell array where each cell is a different RGB color
colors = arrayfun(@(x)rand(1,3), t, 'UniformOutput', false);

set(t, {'Color'}, colors)
```